# Matching Columns in Excel: different files

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have two excel files, One with product ID and description in English. Other one with the same ID and Description, but in French, but the IDs are not in same order in both files, they are listed randomly but both have the same IDs. (there are over 10000 products in the list.)

I want a formula such that I can find all the products by it's ID, Match ID with the IDs in the second file (the French one) and paste all the French description right beside English description column.

How can I make this process faster, I would have done it manually but there are 10,000 items in the list so it would take a lot of time for me.

Comment: If the ID is unique, you can use VLOOKUP, check this https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-from-another-workbook

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Index- Match

Where your ID is in Column A and Description is in Column B

```
=INDEX([Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(A1,[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A,0),1)
```

Or you could use Vlookup IF only two Columns involve

```
=Vlookup(A1,[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0)
```